# Why doesn't \\ display a newline in mathjax?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am under the impression that you should use `\\` for newlines with mathjax, however I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="math display">\[
    1 x x^2 \\
    1 y y^2 \\
    1 z z^2 \\
\]</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see 3 lines, but I get this:

[image: unexpected formatting]

Other stackoverflow posts claim that `\\` should work, eg: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11720/new-line-within-mathjax

Comment: This is a regression in v3 https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2312

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use HTML to break lines as MathJax only handles math mode and does not process the backslashes:

```
<p>
    <span class="math display">
        \(1 x x^2 \)</br>
        \(1 y y^2 \)</br>
        \(1 z z ^2 \)</br>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I don't understand how OP accepted this answer. They ask for a MatJax newline solution and you tell them to use HTML... Besides, \\( and \\) are for inline code, which OP obviously doesn't want.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently \\ is not implemented (yet) in version 3, but you can use \displaylines instead:

```
\displaylines{ first line \\ second line }
```

Comment: this worked using version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out the in the [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62583406/why-doesnt-display-a-newline-in-mathjax/62583532#comment110684012_62583406), this doesn't work in mathjax 3.0.

As a work around, I found the following markdown correctly transforms to HTML with pandoc:

```
you can use this:

\begin{equation}
\displaylines{I = \int \rho R^{2} dV \\ Y = 1}
\end{equation}

or alternatively an align block, e.g:

$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
I & = \int \rho R^{2} dV & + P \\
Y & = 1 & + x
\end{alignat}
$$
```

with: `pandoc --from=markdown --to=html5 --mathjax="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js" -s file.md -o file.html`

Answer (score 0):

@stevenvh solution worked, but I needed them aligned to the left. To do this I found

```
\begin{align}
& ...expression... \\
& ...expression... \\ 
\end{align}
```

to be working.